# What does "You are sympa" mean?

Tags: definiciones, expresiones, significado, coloquialismos

Is "sympa" just an abbreviation of ["sympatico"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sympatico)? Or is there another connotation to it?

I have heard it addressed directly to me, but also small kids and babies described with it.

What exactly does "sympa" mean?

Thanks I only heard the word from a Spanish speaker and have not asked where she got it from. So it being of french origin can make sense especially since the definition seems to match exactly. Thanks

Comment: AS other said, "sympa" is a french word. One says "tu es sympa!".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reference you provided does not state that "sympa" is by any means a word in Spanish. That *sympatico* may be an English slang, probably originated from the Spanish [*simpático*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=simpatico) (Although it could very well be originated from the French [*sympathique*](http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/g/sympa.htm)), but that does not mean that "sympa" has a real meaning in Spanish.

When I have heard "simpa" (sounds the same; different spelling) in Spanish, it's almost always "hacer un simpa", meaning "(Nos vamos) **sin pa**gar de este sitio".

> El camarero tarda mucho con la cuenta. Deberíamos hacer un *simpa*.
>
> Ese restaurante era tan malo que nos entraron ganas de hacer un *simpa*

Comment: Un ejemplo sobre [Hacer un "simpa"](http://noticias.lainformacion.com/espana/el-pequeno-nicolas-detenido-por-hacer-un-simpa-en-un-restaurante-de-madrid_bcYBRfODruPQtSjpiSsjM/)

Comment: +1 por el de hacer un simpa.  Pero no sé si disfruta de uso panhispánico (dúdolo).

Comment: *Sympa* is very usual in French, indeed. In Spanish, the only meaning I know is what you explain in your answer, though it is probably only used in Spain slang.

Comment: I strongly believe it refers to the French word *sympa* as Gorpik said.

Comment: @NicholasJ. I strongly agree. I don't know why the OP thought _sympa_ was Spanish slang. The reference provided has an example in English (nothing leads to think that this word is actually used in Spanish) and with that spelling I would bet it comes from French rather than Spanish. Nevertheless, I think that the answer to the original question still is "_Sympa_ has no meaning in Spanish", regardless which language the word came from.

Answer (score 1):

The proof it's not the spanish word you are refering to, is that you have spelled it with a `y`, and not a `i`.

"Sympa" is a french word, used in "tu es sympa!" or "c'est sympa!". It's more friendly and casual than "sympathique" that has a more formal meaning.